# Yarn: check if installed packages match yarn.lock and/or packages.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

Is there a Yarn command that compares the node_modules folder with yarn.lock to see if it matches? Alternatively, is there a way to check if new packages have been added to packages.json since the last time `yarn install` was ran?

Comment: Just run `yarn`?

Comment: I have a similar need, which is a command that specifically *doesn't* update `node_modules`, but merely detects that `yarn.lock` is out of sync with the `node_modules` contents.  Use case:  a repo where `yarn.lock` is checked in, and code is running out of `node_modules`.  When changes are made to `yarn.lock`, I want to be able to automatically detect it (without making changes) so that I have an opportunity to shut down the running code during `yarn install` and relaunch.